# Isn't fb_sig_friends supposed to be there?

Tags: php, facebook

According to [the docs](http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/Automatic_Authentication),  Facebook is supposed to send both `fb_sig_canvas_user` and `fb_sig_friends` for a canvas application. Sadly, I only get `fb_sig_canvas_user` and NOT `fb_sig_friends`. Is there anything I have to do to get this parameter?

Or is there any other way to retrieve the friends of the visiting (not-yet-authorized) user, without the need of a session key (API throws exception with message "Requires user session" if no such key is present)?

And yes, `_fb_fromhash` is present in the request (when coming to the canvas app. from a user's application tab).

It makes no difference if the accounts being friends to each other are test accounts or normal Facebook accounts.

Answer (score 0):

According to the Facebook FAQ's, the automatic authentication isn't available anymore:

http://www.facebook.com/help/?faq=217357081622238